# How many Ah do I need for 12V battery to power 76 LED lights (0.84watt each) using a 500W inverter to power for 6 hours?

Tags: power-supply, led, batteries, battery-operated, 12v

Looking to build a power pack with a 12V battery to inverter in order to power 4 string lights totaling 76 LED bulbs each with 0.84 wattage. Total time to keep lights on is 6 hours. How many Ah do I need in a 12V battery to accomplish this? Is there a better solution?

Comment: 76 * .84 * 6 / 12.  Then factor in the efficiency of your inverter (add about 20%) if you aren't powering them directly. Then double it at least, because you don't want to discharge a lead acid battery below 50%; that shortens the battery life a lot.

Comment: eliminating the inverter would be an improvement

Comment: How would I eliminate the inverter ? I’ve never tried something like this before but need a power pack.

Comment: use 12 V LEDs   .